# Interview topic: Binary search for a range

Tags: java, binary-search

I feel a little frustrated because they did not hire me for not achieving the goal, but I think it is not possible.

The Problem:
"*Given an array with sorted data, e.g. 
  0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 15
Write a java class that implements binary search in O(log(n)) to find all instances of element X (for instance X=7), and the accompanying JUnit unit tests. Return all the indices if the element is found at least once, or -1 if not found. Explicitly identify any assumption you are making while solving this problem.*"

I find the way to get the left index and right index of the element in log(n) time.

But how can you return ALL THE INDICES in log(n) time, any idea?

Comment: maybe...in a list?

Comment: Assuming the 7's are split between the right and left subtrees under root you will need to do two log(n) traversals which is 2log(2) and in big O terms that is still log(n).

Comment: So if you do a binary search on the array and find one of the 7's. Why not just iterate to lower and higher indices until there are no more 7's, and then return a list of all the indices that had the 7?

Comment: I can find the lower and higher indices in 2log(n) time that is O(log(n)), but i can't create a list of the indices in log(n), i need n time to assign the indices for every item in the list.

Comment: I would suggest  you could document an "assumption" that you can only promise `O(log n + m)` where `n` is the array size and `m` the number of elements found.

Comment: @Arkadiy exactly

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case, such as if the list were all "7"s, @Duarte Meneses' method of walking outward to find both ends would take O(n), not O(log n).

If you find both ends by binary search (as OP says they did), and just return the *indexes* to both ends, that would be O(log n).

But if the questioner precisely intended to exclude that when they asked you to "return all the indexes", then in the worst case you can't do it, because there are more than log n items to return, and merely making the list to return would take longer than O(log n) -- even if you magically *found* them all in 0 time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to implement binarySearch for you because you can find many  code examples online that do just that. Instead, I'll demonstrate what you can do once you've found one of the indices of the number you're looking for:

The algorithm is pretty simple, you iterate backwards until you reach the first occurrence of the number, and then iterate forward and add all the indices into a result list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 15 };
    List<Integer> indices = findIndices(arr, 7);
    System.out.println(indices);
}

static List<Integer> findIndices(int[] arr, int num) {
    // here we may have one of the indices of 7: [6, 7, 8, 9]
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, num);
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();

    if (index < 0) { // not found
        result.add(-1);
    } else {  // found, now go backwards till the first one
        while (index > 0 && arr[index-1] == num) {
            index--;
        }
        // add all indices to the result-list
        while (arr[index] == num) {
            result.add(index++);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this algorithm is O(n) time complexity not O(log(n))

Comment: @AlexanderPinzonFernandez when you have repetitions and you want to find *all* the indices *any* algorithm is O(n) simply because you may get a list such as: 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7...,7 (adding all the indices in the list will take O(n) regardless of how quickly you've found the higher and lower bounds).

Answer (score 0):

Finding the index of an element using binary search would take log(n) time. Since the array is sorted you can print out the element next to that index. That should take log(n)+k, where k is the number of occurences and that should be still log(n) depending of course how many times the searched element occurs.